# Local file blob save

Tags: windows, azure, save, blob, local

I am a bit stuck with this Windows Azure Blob storage.

I have a controller that receive a file path (local).

So on the web page I do something loke this:

http:...?filepath=C:/temp/myfile.txt

On the web service I want to get this file and put it on the blob service. When I launch it in local there is no problem but when i publish it there is no way to get the file. I always get:
Error encountered: Could not find a part of the path 'C:/temp/myfile.txt'.

Can someone help me. Is there a solution ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First i would say to get proper help you would need to provide better description about your problem. What do you mean by "On the web service"? Is it a WCF web role which seems to match with your partial problem description. However most of the web service use http://whatever.cloudapp.net/whatever.svc as well as http://whatever.cloudapp.net/whaterever.aspx?whatever if added. Have you done something like that in your application.

You have also mentioned the controller in your code which makes me think it is a MVC based Web Role application.

I am writing above information to help you to formulate your question much better next time.

Finally Based on what you have provided you are reading a file from local file system (C:\temp\myfile.txt) and uploading to Azure Blob. This will work in compute Emulator and sure will fail in Windows Azure because:

In your Web Role code you will not have access to write on C:\ drive and that's why file is not there and you get error. Your best bet is to use Azure Local Storage to write any content there and then use Local Storage to read the file and then upload the Azure Blob. Azure Local storage is designed to write any content from web role (you will have write permission).

Finally,  I am concern with your application design also because Azure VM are no persisted so having a solution to write to anywhere in VM is not good and you may need to directly write to Azure storage without using system memory, if that is possible anyways.

Comment: I am trying to use the local storage but there is a thing I don't understand. When I call Rootpath, it returns a path to a file but there is no such file in my local computer.

Answer (score 0):

Did you verify the file exists on the Azure server?

Comment: I don't want to get the file from the Azure blob Storage. I want to get a local computer file and put it in the blob storage.

Comment: Does the full path to the file have to be specified on the query string?  Ideally you'd reference local files by using the local storage option available in Windows Azure.

Comment: Yes. If you think of the HttpPostedFileBase i can't use this. I will search on the local storage option but what I've already found was not very good.

Comment: Would you be able to outline the scenario a little bit (just some basic steps)? I think that might help provide a better idea for a solution.

Comment: Yes sure.

1) I save a file from a local application : myfile.txt
2) In the application I call my controller using the adress http:.../Add?filepath=C:/temp/myfile.txt
3) In my controller.Add(string filepath), I do all the blob initialization stuff (no problem with that) but when i do blob.UploadFromFile(filepath) I encounter the error : Could not find a part of the path 'C:/temp/myfile.txt'.
As I said, when I execute it in local with VS2010 there is no problem the file is saved in the blob storage service but when I use the published version, i get the error.

Comment: Is this 'local application' a web app?  Like AvkashChauhan mentions in his answer below, local storage is OK for temp storage, but not great for anything permenant.  One approach may be to write everything to blob storage directly and never use local storage.  The web app (assuming it is a web app) and the web service would 'know' to reference a specfic storage account and blob container and construct the appropriate path.